# Reading white spaces, new lines and tabs with regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to capture white spaces `\s`, end of lines `'\n'`, `'\r'`, tabs `'\t'`, but not having success.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
std::regex s ("\\s(.*)");
std::regex n ("\\n(.*)");
std::regex r ("\\r(.*)");
std::regex t ("\\t(.*)");
const char str[]=" subject \rsubject \nsubject \tsubject";
std::cmatch cmS;
std::cmatch cmN;
std::cmatch cmR;
std::cmatch cmT;
 if (std::regex_match (str, cmS,s))
     for (unsigned i=0; i<cmS.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << "[" << cmS[i] << "] ";
     }
 if (std::regex_match (str, cmN,n))
     for (unsigned i=0; i<cmN.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << "[" << cmN[i] << "] ";
     }
 if (std::regex_match (str, cmR,r))
     for (unsigned i=0; i<cmR.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << "[" << cmR[i] << "] ";
     }

 if (std::regex_match (str, cmT,t))
     for (unsigned i=0; i<cmT.size(); ++i) {
         std::cout << "[" << cmT[i] << "] ";
     }

return 0;
}
```

I also tried like this but didn't have any success either and my program was crashing:

```
if (std::regex_match ("subject subject", std::regex("\\s(sub)"),std::regex_constants::ECMAScript ))
    std::cout << "string literal matched\n";

if (std::regex_match ("subject subject", std::regex("\s(sub)"),std::regex_constants::ECMAScript ))
    std::cout << "string literal matched\n";

if (std::regex_match ("subject subject", std::regex("[[:s:]](sub)"),std::regex_constants::ECMAScript ))
    std::cout << "string literal matched\n";
```

I know there are some external classes like `boost` to do `regex` in C++, but my goal is to not use any external classes and dependencies for my program, so I need to do this inside C++ itself.

Comment: Try [`regex_search`](https://ideone.com/kZmkg4). Does it fix your code?

Comment: Could you please provide the expected output? It does not make sense to match a symbol that you know unless you need to split with it, or say, find its position.

Comment: @stribizhev `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
what(): regex_error`. App terminates itself with this output by regex library when first regex pattern is created.

Comment: What is your library version? Update to the GCC 4.9.0 or higher.

Comment: It's GCC 4.8.1. I will update to 4.9.0 later on and report if it works.

Comment: On GCC < 4.9.0, regex does not work. So, you need to install the GCC 4.9.0+, and then try with `regex_search`, and you will get [these results](https://ideone.com/kZmkg4). Please let me know if that works for you. Please use user name tags (@username), or we'll not get any notifications from SO.

Comment: @stribizhev I've updated my GCC and it works fine now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enable the regex, you need to install GCC 4.9.0 or higher as in the former compile versions regex module did not work.

Next, you need to use `regex_search` rather than `regex_match`, as the latter requires a full string match, and you are looking for substrings.

See `regex_match` description:

> The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this function to return true (i.e., without any additional characters before or after the match). For a function that returns true when the match is only part of the sequence, see [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/regex_search).

Comment: I was struggling with a regex that was working on a different machine but not mine. Then I realized that I was using 4.8. Somehow, it compiles but it does not return the expected output. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to match the white space then i see no need for you adding `(.*)`

Try removing (.*) in each of your statement. Your new statement should now be like this

```
std::regex s ("\\s"); 
std::regex n ("\\n"); 
std::regex r ("\\r");
std::regex t ("\\t");
```